# Blazor opening double modal popup

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor

When I click on this link 2  modal pop ups will appear. What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

```
 <a @onclick="@(()=>ShowModal(pd.StudentId))" > <i title="document" class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>
```

```cs
protected async Task ShowModal(int st) 
{
    var parameters = new ModalParameters();
    parameters.Add(nameof(Downloadfile.StudentId), st);
    
    var options = new ModalOptions() 
    {
        DisableBackgroundCancel = true,
        Animation = ModalAnimation.FadeInOut(1),
    };

    //  Modal.OnClose += ModalClosed;
    Modal.Show < Downloadfile > ("File To Be Download", parameters, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure how you are displaying the modal popup so I am assuming that it is because of the async in your `ShowModal` method. If you don't have any awaits in there, you can remove it to be like this:

`protected void ShowModal(int st)`

Or if you have any awaits in that method you need to change your link to add async with it:

`<a @onclick="@(async ()=> await ShowModal(pd.StudentId))" > <i title="document" class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>`

*If this doesn't work, please share more code for modal popup.*

Comment: I tried with @(async ()=> await ShowModal(pd.StudentId))" but not work..

Comment: I just remove the  <BlazoredModal /> tag from MainLayout.razor and it works now.. thank you for your suggestion and also its useful for me